# YUI tooltip widget pass class name instead of id?

Tags: javascript, yui

How can I pass a class name to the YUI2tooltip: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/tooltip.html instead of an ID?

I attempted to do this:

```
YAHOO.example.container.tt1 = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(
    YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('annotation-rating'), {
        context:"ctx",
        text:"My text was set using the 'text' configuration property"});

YAHOO.example.container.tt2 = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip(
    YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('annotation-rating'), {
        context:"link" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since YAHOO.widget.tooltip can only accept one element, the selector needs to be more specific:

```
YAHOO.util.DOM.getElementsByClassName(className, tagName, rootNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/) it looks like you switched the id and context parameters.

The id parameter seems to be for the ids of the individual generated tooltips (pass null since we aren't using them?) and the context argument is for the element(s) that are being converted to tooltips:

```
YAHOO.example.container.tt1 = new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip( null, {
    context: YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('annotation-rating'),
    text:"My text was set using the 'text' configuration property"
});
```

---

Caveat - I don't really use YUI so I don't know if this works...

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didn't work though. I'm not sure if the tooltip widget can accept more than one element as the context. I'm not a fan of YUI but forced to use it. I can't stand the docs.

Comment: @spyderman4g63 :/ Perhaps you can instead create them inside a loop, passing each node one at a time instead of the whole array at once?